# Appendix header to show like "Appendix A. Chapter name"

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

In the MWE below, I wanted to get the appendix header to show up like:

Appendix A. Chapter name.

In the MWE, just the Chapter name shows up.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum, fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}}
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage}

\begin{document}
\part{Intro}
\lipsum{1-4}

\part{Appendix}
\appendix
\chapter{This is test A}
\lipsum
\chapter{This is test B}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have any other chapters in the document? What about before `\part{Appendix}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum, fancyhdr}

%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \ #1}{}}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}}


\begin{document}
\part{Intro}
\lipsum{1-4}

\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\sffamily\normalsize\leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\part{Appendix}
\appendix
\chapter{This is test A}
\lipsum
\chapter{This is test B}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]